# How to return the NAME of greater of two variables in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

This could obviously be done with an if-elif-else logic, but I wish to ask for a better - more pythonic way to implement it. eg.

```
a,b = 14,73
if a>b:
    print('a')
elif a<b:
    print('b')
else:
    print('a=b') #not_required_though
```

Comment: you can use dictionary

Comment: if you need the variable name, most likely there is problem with your design ([Keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). As @deadshot mention - you may use `dict` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do if else in one line

```
print('a' if a>b else 'b')
```

or you can also assign it to variable

```
res = 'a' if a>b else 'b' if b>a else 'a==b'
```

Comment: I meant the variable name, not the value of the variable.